# Position of not in the sentence below

Tags: verb-pattern

I'm a bit confused with: I warn you not to do this and I warn you to not do this. Do these sentences mean the same?

Comment: They do but the second is not idiomatic.

Comment: I disagree with the previous comment; both versions are idiomatic. There is a subtle difference in meaning. The first can be interpreted to mean simply not to do it; however, the second can be interpreted to mean to *actively* refrain from doing it. (It's a little like the difference between simply not turning left and deliberately turning right.)